# Changing number of threads in Pooling connection manager in java at runtime

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to implement a project which uses [`ThreadSafeClientConnManager`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html), with 20 as a maximum threads in the pool. Now, depending on the traffic, I want to change the number of threads at runtime. Is it possible to do it?

I have one solution that could work is, I have a new set of threadpool which I initialize when changing the max connections, and then replace the existing one. Kind of buffer switch. but I am not sure if that is the optimal solution.

Comment: Can you show some of your code showing how you are swapping in the new pool?

Comment: Why not give it your maximum, maximum thread count?  Idle threads don't give much overhead.

Comment: The reason is that the max connection is generally a multiplication factor of max connections per host. So, if I give max to both max per host, and max connections as same, it could be possible that one connection may consume all the threads in my thread pool.

Comment: @Gray The general idea we use is we have an method calling getConnection(String host), which is implemented in a way to get your a thread based on the host, we do a this.connectionpool.getThread();  All I do now, is instead of connectionpool, I have currentConnectionPool object, which could be substituted to another values if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that now you are using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`. This pool cannot be resized dynamically, unfortunately.

A better solution that is adaptive would be the `Executors.newCachedThreadPool`. Take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29).

> Calls to execute will reuse previously constructed threads if
>   available. If no existing thread is available, a new thread will be
>   created and added to the pool. Threads that have not been used for
>   sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache.